# How to display progress text using ProgressRing

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

How can I display text about the progress (not necessarily %) using a `ProgressRing` control?

Comment: here is a more in depth example with source code hope this helps in what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191840/adding-a-progress-bar-when-navigating-from-page-to-another-in-windws-8-apps-usin

Comment: Thanks but I already know how to use the ProgressRing control. What I need is to add a text at top or bottom of the ring displaying a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create custom control inherited from ProgressRing and change standart ProgressRing [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709924.aspx).

[The Sample](http://shreychouhan.blogspot.ru/2011/04/extend-functionality-to-wpf-control.html) how can you do it. One more [sample](http://brianlagunas.com/2012/03/06/create-your-first-winrt-watermarktextbox-control/) for WinRT.

**Update** `ProgressRing` is sealed.

You may try to put `TextBlock` over your `ProgressRing` and write your progress information in `TextBlock` directly.